# SOAP to Restlets strategy for multiple methods

Tags: java, web-services, rest, restlet

I've been working with the Restlet library for the last couple weeks and from what I can see it is fairly impressive. The ability to be able to define a common interface for consumption by both the client and server surpasses any messy soap frameworks I've worked with.

However, something has been plaguing my mind that I just can get past:

Is there a good way to define Restlets with many methods?

My primary use case is that I have a soap web service that has 10-15 or so methods in it. As I see it, if I wish to translate this over to a Restlet I will need to separate this out into 8-15 interfaces depending on which methods become get methods vs post or put - I don't think you can have more than one verb method (get, post, put, etc) per interface. This seems like a cumbersome and clumsy solution.

I've thought of using some type of factory\map technique to mitigate this - but I wanted to make sure I'm not missing something better first.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [JAX-RS extension](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.1/13-restlet/28-restlet/57-restlet.html) for Restlet. JAX-RS provides the [`@Path`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/javadoc/jax-rs/1.0/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) annotation that is used identify the URI of the resource. Paths can be attached either to the type or to a method. Routing should be then done by the container instead of explicitly defining router rules.

Comment: This looks very promising. I'll have to check it out. +1

Comment: This extension does not provide a client though, do you have any suggestions for that?

Answer (score 3):

Even though coming from a SOAP background, it might be surprising, what you observe it actually a good thing because your web API is becoming more and more RESTful.

In REST/HTTP, methods are standard and limited (by design) and to compensate we create as many resources/URis as necessary.

Regarding JAX-RS, it doesn't have the same client/server uniformity. I would recommend staying with the core Restlet API in general as it is more powerful/extensible.

If you could list your method names, that would help suggest a proper mapping to HTTP resource and methods, I'm not sure you need that many interfaces in the end. Even if this is the case, there server-side implementation will be easy and more maintainable which also has benefits.

Hope this helps

Comment: I recognized your name immediately and let me say - so far, my usage of the framework has me very pleased. Well done! The one thing that has left me looking at other rest frameworks is the uri path mapping. With the JAX-RS extension you can define paths in the interface without the need for a router. However, there doesn't seem to be a corresponding client in restlet. I tried CXF, but it doesn't do automatic content mapping like restlet - so I feel at a bit of a loss. Suggestions?